# Algorithm to quickly map out relationships among millions of objects

Tags: database, performance, algorithm, search-engine, relationship

I have a relational database table with millions of rows, each is linked to hundreds of  rows within this table. It a simple relationship but becomes problematic when there are millions of rows. Each time a new row is added it has to scan the entire range.

Is there a more efficient way to perform this operation?

I'm sure search engines have solved this problem already on an even larger scale. (Is there a term for this kind of problems?)

Comment: What do you mean "scan the entire range"? Could you give us more information about what you are tying to do - do this in *English*, without presupposing any implementation.

Comment: each row is linked other rows based on matching keywords. When a new row is being added the system has to scan every row in the table to find matches. it could be zero or hundreds of matches.

Comment: Why does it "have to find matches"? Again, what is it in English that you are trying to do? Forget about "rows", "tables" and "data". Just tell us the intent.

Comment: each row has location nvarchar field (name of city,state,country), it's linking to other rows produced in the same location

Answer (score 0):

A standard database system would use indexes so that you could process new rows without a linear scan of the entire database.

A traditional text search system would process a large amount of impact in a batch, for instance sorting all the words to build an inverted index. It would wait for some time to accumulate (or gather from the web) enough input to make a batch run worthwhile - so you spread the cost of a batch process over a large amount of input. You can then either merge the results of processing a batch with the accumulated data so far, or keep it separate and search more than one chunk of indexed data when the user submits a query.

I can't produce anything more specific without a more specific question from you, but you might find that extracting the keywords from a large number of input rows and sorting them to produce a single list of sorted keywords helps the matching process, or perhaps keeping an inverted index of keywords in all the rows currently stored.